# Mono.Cecil - can't import constructors

Tags: mono.cecil

I've injected an empty method into a class. I'm now trying to fill it with this simple following code:

```
Affliction test = new Affliction ();
if (test != null)
    Console.AddMessage ("not null");
```

I've converted this snippet into ILCode with Reflexil and it works fine when I inject it with Reflexil itself.

However, when I inject the same ilcode instructions with Cecil, I get an error when running the program and I also can't open it in .Net Reflector.
This is the ILcode that I'm injecting:

```
IL_0000: newobj System.Void Affliction::.ctor()
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldnull
IL_0008: call System.Boolean Affliction::op_Inequality(Affliction,Affliction)
IL_0013: brfalse.s IL_0025
IL_0015: ldstr "not null"
IL_0020: call System.Void Console:AddMessage(System.String)
IL_0025: ret
```

This is how I do it:

```
System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constrInfo = typeof(Affliction).GetConstructors()[0];
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Newobj, mainMod.Import (constrInfo)));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_0));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_0));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldnull));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, mainMod.Import(typeof(Affliction).GetMethod ("op_Inequality"))));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, newMethod.Body.Instructions[1])); // instruction reference will be changed later
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "not null"));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, mainMod.Import(typeof(Console).GetMethod("AddMessage", new Type[]{typeof(String)}))));
newMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
newMethod.Body.Instructions [5].Operand = newMethod.Body.Instructions [8];
```

The inspection of the resulting instructions shows exactly what I'm aiming for. And yet they don't work.

Here's the error I get in the program: **InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in CommandLine:TestCecil (): IL_0005: stloc.0**

And .Net Reflector throws an error saying **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

This makes me think that the first instruction **Newobj** for some reason can't create an object and doesn't push the reference onto the evaluation stack. Then, the next instruction **stloc.0** can't pop it and put it into the list of local variables, and this throws errors. When I reference normal methods in the same way, they are called just fine, but the constructors produce errors. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jb Evain** answered the question on the Google Group, so I'll just leave his answer here in case somebody else has this problem.

> Hi,
>
> I think you're just missing one thing: you're not creating the
>   variable.
>
> You need to add a VariableDefinition to newMethod.Body.Variables.
>   Otherwise stloc.0 has no variable at index 0.